# SecureRandom locking NativePRNG on jsch

Tags: java, linux, random, jsch

I have an application on production that creates about 150 threads that complete in about 45 seconds. Recently we started to have memory problems. Turns out that threads never complete and add up over time because of locked NativePRNG.

We only have that problem for our test/backup machine. Production machine runs the same jar without a problem.

Here's the stack trace of a thread

```
"VSGADNE01" #923 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7698e41800 nid=0x2b32 runnable 
[0x00007f7601ac3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3520)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:553)
    - locked <0x00000005cdf9c660> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$400(NativePRNG.java:331)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:220)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:468)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.jce.Random.fill(Random.java:78)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Packet.padding(Packet.java:59)
    - locked <0x00000005cde992d0> (a com.jcraft.jsch.jce.Random)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.encode(Session.java:885)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session._write(Session.java:1366)
    - locked <0x000000064974f720> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.write(Session.java:1335)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.sendPacketPath(ChannelSftp.java:2575)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.sendPacketPath(ChannelSftp.java:2559)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.sendCLOSE(ChannelSftp.java:2538)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._sendCLOSE(ChannelSftp.java:2464)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._get(ChannelSftp.java:1155)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:961)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:873)
    at com.ngss.vodafone.oss.ebm.Controller.SftpUtils.getFiles(SftpUtils.java:141)
    at com.ngss.vodafone.oss.ebm.Controller.SftpUtils.download(SftpUtils.java:187)
    at com.ngss.vodafone.oss.ebm.Controller.Host.downloadFiles(Host.java:108)
    at com.ngss.vodafone.oss.ebm.Controller.Host.run(Host.java:86)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Things that i tried with no success:

- Setting securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom in java.security
- Running the jar with option -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
- Linking /dev/random to /dev/urandom

`java -version` of these 2 machines:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

Both machines are Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)

Comment: You should provide more details, especially which Java version and vendor you use. Also which OS (version, kernel, ..). Also you should read this article: https://tersesystems.com/blog/2015/12/17/the-right-way-to-use-securerandom/

Comment: I updated the question with more info. Also i don't use SecureRandom directly, jsch does.

Comment: JSch is open source, therefore if you have runtime problems that require editing the source code this should not be an obstacle.